# How to generate test data with shuffle in QuickCeck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

For a given list [1..n], where n is a random positive integer, I want to generate the test data with 2 steps:

1. Shuffle the list, xs = shuffle [1..n];
2. Random mutate a number x in xs to y, where 1 <= y <= n;

After these 2 steps, the new list is denoted as ys.

I wrote a program. It takes ys, and outputs (x, y), the function prototype is like this:

```
solve :: [a] -> (a, a)
```

I want to use Test.QuickCheck to test my program. How to generate such test data? I see there is a function in QuickCheck

```
shuffle :: [a] -> Gen [a]
```

But I have no idea about how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Gen` monad in QuickCheck is basically a state monad with a random number generator as its state. So when you see

```
shuffle :: [a] -> Gen [a]
```

That means that this argument takes a list and returns a shuffled list "in" the `Gen` monad.

Because its a monad you can put it inside a `do` clause. Its not quite clear what you are asking for, but I think its something like this:

```
myTest :: Integer -> Gen [Integer]
myTest 0 = return []
myTest n = do
   ns <- shuffle [1..n]
   x <- choose (0,n-1)
   y <- choose (1,n)
   let (ns1,ns2) = splitAt x ns
   return $ ns1 ++ [y] ++ drop 1 ns2`
```

You can run an action in the Gen monad using `generate`, which returns a value in `IO`, or you can set up a new type for your test data and make it an instance of `Arbitrary`, which contains the function

```
arbitrary :: Gen a
```

**Edit:** Or as Zeta pointed out in the comments you can use `forAll`:

```
quickCheck $ forAll (myTest 10) $ \x -> ....
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a Sample data type, and provided the arbitrary function. like this: https://github.com/liuxinyu95/AlgoXY/blob/algoxy/others/problems/miss-dup/MissDup.hs

Comment: Or you use `quickCheck $ forAll (myTest 10) $ \x -> ...`.